# Using find within lambda passing two variables

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

I am taking a course on python and we are working on lambda expressions and I am stuck when trying to pass two variables. Consider this:

```
lis = ['today', 'is', 'a', 'nice', 'day']
print(list(map(lambda x: x.find('i'), lis)))
output:
[-1, 0, -1, 1, -1]
```

However, this only returns -1:

```
s = 'today is a nice day'
def find_char(sentence, string):
    sentence = sentence.split()
    return list(map(lambda x, y: print(x), sentence, string))
print(find_char(s, 'i'))
```

The lambda function only passes the first word, today, rather than each word. Why is this happening, and how can I get the function to return the same list as the first method using lambda?

Thank you.

Comment: When you pass multiple iterables to `map`, each iterable is iterated over, and passed to the function, until the shortest one is exhausted. In your case, the second iterable, (`string`) is only 1 character long. So only the first value from each iterable will be passed to the function.

Comment: Got it, I added string *= len(sentence) and it's working as expected. Thank you for your help.